# How can i make my rating work in my flutter e-commerce app

Tags: android, flutter, dart

I’m working on an ecommerce flutter and laravel project and it is supposed to show the ratings of the products using rating bar builder but it isn’t working at all and it doesn’t update the ratings

This is my products model code

```
import 'dart:convert';

import 'package:yeabrak_gebeya/data/models/category.dart';
import 'package:yeabrak_gebeya/data/models/owner.dart';

class Product {
  final String id;
  final Map<String, String> name;
  final String categoryId;
  final String ownerId;
  final String productUnitId;
  final bool hasDiscount;
  final Map<String, String> description;
  final Category category;
  final double rating;
  final double price;`your text`
  final double discountPercent;
  final int unit;
  final String brandName;
  final List<String> productImages;
  final Owner owner;

  Product({
    required this.id,
    required this.categoryId,
    required this.ownerId,
    required this.productUnitId,
    required this.name,
    required this.description,
    required this.category,
    required this.rating,
    required this.price,
    required this.unit,
    required this.hasDiscount,
    required this.discountPercent,
    required this.brandName,
    required this.productImages,
    required this.owner,
  });

  Map<String, dynamic> toMap() {
    return {
      'id': id,
      'name': name,
      'category_id': categoryId,
      'owner_id': ownerId,
      'product_unit_id': productUnitId,
      'description': description,
      'category': category.toMap(),
      'rating': rating,
      'price': price,
      'unit': unit,
      'has_discount': hasDiscount,
      'discount_percent': discountPercent,
      'brand': brandName,
      'product_images': productImages,
      'owner': owner.toMap(),
    };
  }

  factory Product.fromMap(Map<String, dynamic> map) {
    return Product(
      id: map['id'] ?? '',
      name: Map<String, String>.from(map['name']),
      categoryId: map['category_id'] ?? '',
      ownerId: map['owner_id'] ?? '',
      productUnitId: map['product_unit_id'] ?? '',
      description: Map<String, String>.from(map['description']),
      category: Category.fromMap(map['category']),
      rating: double.tryParse(map['rating'].toString()) ?? 0.0,
      price: double.tryParse(map['price']) ?? 0.0,
      unit: int.tryParse(map['unit'] ?? "0")!,
      hasDiscount: map['has_discount'] ?? false,
      discountPercent: map['discount_percent'] ?? 0.0,
      brandName: map['brand'] ?? '',
      productImages: List<String>.from(map['product_images']),
      owner: Owner.fromMap(map['owner']),
    );
  }

  String toJson() => json.encode(toMap());

  factory Product.fromJson(String source) =>
      Product.fromMap(json.decode(source));

  Product copyWith({
    String? id,
    Map<String, String>? name,
    String? categoryId,
    String? ownerId,
    String? productUnitId,
    Map<String, String>? description,
    Category? category,
    double? rating,
    double? price,
    int? unit,
    bool? hasDiscount,
    double? discountPercent,
    String? brandName,
    List<String>? productImages,
    Owner? owner,
  }) {
    return Product(
      id: id ?? this.id,
      name: name ?? this.name,
      categoryId: categoryId ?? this.categoryId,
      ownerId: ownerId ?? this.ownerId,
      productUnitId: productUnitId ?? this.productUnitId,
      description: description ?? this.description,
      category: category ?? this.category,
      rating: rating ?? this.rating,
      price: price ?? this.price,
      unit: unit ?? this.unit,
      hasDiscount: hasDiscount ?? this.hasDiscount,
      discountPercent: discountPercent ?? this.discountPercent,
      brandName: brandName ?? this.brandName,
      productImages: productImages ?? this.productImages,
      owner: owner ?? this.owner,
    );
  }
}
```

This is my review model code

```
import 'dart:convert';

import 'package:yeabrak_gebeya/data/models/user.dart';

class Review {

  final String id;

  final String productId;

  final String createdTime;

  final String description;

  final double rating;

  final User user;

  Review({

    required this.id,

    required this.productId,

    required this.createdTime,

    required this.description,

    required this.rating,

    required this.user,

  });

  Map<String, dynamic> toMap() {

    return {

      'id': id,

      'product_id': productId,

      'created_at': createdTime,

      'comment': description,

      'rating': rating,

      'user': user.toMap(),

    };

  }

  factory Review.fromMap(Map<String, dynamic> map) {

    return Review(

      id: map['id'] ?? '',

      productId: map['product_id'] ?? '',

      createdTime: map['created_at'] ?? '',

      description: map['comment'] ?? '',

      rating: double.tryParse(map['rating']) ?? 0.0,

      user: User.fromMap(map['user']),

    );

  }

  String toJson() => json.encode(toMap());

  factory Review.fromJson(String source) => Review.fromMap(json.decode(source));

}
```

This code fetches the products

```
import "package:http/http.dart" as http;
import "package:yeabrak_gebeya/utils/constants/endpoints.dart";

class ProductsClient {
  final headers = {
    'Content-Type': 'application/json',
    'Accept': 'application/json',
  };
  Future<http.Response> getAllProducts() async {
    var request = await http.get(
        headers: headers, Uri.parse(ProductEndpoints.getProducts));

    return request;
  }

  Future<http.Response> getSearchedProducts(
      {required String searchPrompt}) async {
    var request = await http.get(
        headers: headers,
        Uri.parse("${ProductEndpoints.getSearchedProducts}$searchPrompt"));

    return request;
  }

  Future<http.Response> getLatestProducts() async {
    var request = await http.get(
        headers: headers, Uri.parse(ProductEndpoints.getLatestProducts));

    return request;
  }

  Future<http.Response> getPopularProducts() async {
    var request = await http.get(
        headers: headers, Uri.parse(ProductEndpoints.getPopularProducts));

    return request;
  }

  Future<http.Response> getRelatedProducts({required String productId}) async {
    var request = await http.get(
        headers: headers,
        Uri.parse("${ProductEndpoints.getRelatedProducts}/$productId"));

    return request;
  }

  Future<http.Response> getProductsByCategory(
      {required String categoryId}) async {
    var request = await http.get(
        headers: headers,
        Uri.parse("${ProductEndpoints.getCategoryProducts}/$categoryId"));
    return request;
  }

  Future<http.Response> getProductInfo({required String productId}) async {
    var request = await http.get(
        headers: headers,
        Uri.parse("${ProductEndpoints.getProducts}/$productId"));
    return request;
  }
}
```

This gets all products

```
import 'dart:convert';

import 'package:yeabrak_gebeya/data/client/products_client.dart';
import 'package:yeabrak_gebeya/data/models/product.dart';
import 'package:yeabrak_gebeya/data/models/review.dart';

class ProductsRepo {
  Future<List<Product>> getAllProducts() async {
    final response = await ProductsClient().getAllProducts();

    final List<dynamic> filteredData =
        jsonDecode(response.body)["data"]["data"];

    List<Product> products = [];

    try {
      for (var element in filteredData) {
        products.add(Product.fromMap(element));
      }
    } catch (e) {
      rethrow;
    }

    return products;
  }

  Future<List<Product>> getSearchedProducts(
      {required String searchPrompt}) async {
    final response =
        await ProductsClient().getSearchedProducts(searchPrompt: searchPrompt);

    final List<dynamic> filteredData =
        jsonDecode(response.body)["data"]["data"];

    List<Product> products = [];

    try {
      for (var element in filteredData) {
        products.add(Product.fromMap(element));
      }
    } catch (e) {
      rethrow;
    }

    return products;
  }

  Future<List<Product>> getLatestProducts() async {
    final response = await ProductsClient().getLatestProducts();
    final List<dynamic> filteredData = jsonDecode(response.body)["data"];
    List<Product> products = [];

    try {
      for (var element in filteredData) {
        products.add(Product.fromMap(element));
      }
    } catch (e) {
      rethrow;
    }
    return products;
  }

  Future<List<Product>> getPopularProducts() async {
    final response = await ProductsClient().getPopularProducts();
    final List<dynamic> filteredData = jsonDecode(response.body)["data"];
    List<Product> products = [];

    try {
      for (var element in filteredData) {
        products.add(Product.fromMap(element));
      }
    } catch (e) {
      rethrow;
    }
    return products;
  }

  Future<List<Product>> getRelatedProducts({required String productId}) async {
    final response =
        await ProductsClient().getRelatedProducts(productId: productId);
    final List<dynamic> filteredData = jsonDecode(response.body)["data"];
    List<Product> products = [];
    try {
      for (var element in filteredData) {
        products.add(Product.fromMap(element));
      }
    } catch (e) {
      rethrow;
    }
    return products;
  }

  Future<List<Product>> getCategoryProducts(
      {required String categoryId}) async {
    final response =
        await ProductsClient().getProductsByCategory(categoryId: categoryId);
    final List<dynamic> filteredData = jsonDecode(response.body)["data"];
    List<Product> products = [];
    try {
      for (var element in filteredData) {
        products.add(Product.fromMap(element));
      }
    } catch (e) {
      rethrow;
    }
    return products;
  }

  Future<List<Review>> getProductReviews({required String productId}) async {
    final response =
        await ProductsClient().getProductInfo(productId: productId);

    final List<dynamic> filteredData =
        jsonDecode(response.body)["data"]["product"]["reviews"];

    List<Review> productReviews = [];
    try {
      for (var element in filteredData) {
        productReviews.add(Review.fromMap(element));
      }
    } catch (e) {
      rethrow;
    }
    return productReviews;
  }
}
```

This is my reviews cubit

```
import 'package:bloc/bloc.dart';
import 'package:freezed_annotation/freezed_annotation.dart';
import 'package:yeabrak_gebeya/data/models/review.dart';
import 'package:yeabrak_gebeya/data/repositories/products_repo.dart';

part 'reviews_state.dart';
part 'generated/reviews_cubit.freezed.dart';

class ReviewsCubit extends Cubit<ReviewsState> {
  ReviewsCubit() : super(const ReviewsState.initial());

  Future<void> getProductReviews({required String productId}) async {
    emit(const ReviewsState.loading());
    try {
      final List<Review> productReviews =
          await ProductsRepo().getProductReviews(productId: productId);
      emit(
        ReviewsState.loaded(productReviews: productReviews),
      );
    } catch (e) {
      emit(const ReviewsState.failed());
    }
  }
}
```

[I want it to be visible like this](https://i.stack.imgur.com/da0LL.jpg)
[Using this dialog](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Kkxf7.jpg)

I tried using a popup dialog to update the ratings but they are not working

```
Future<void> showReviewDialog(

    {required BuildContext context,

    required Product product,

    Review? review}) async {

  final TextEditingController descriptionController = TextEditingController();

  final GlobalKey formKey = GlobalKey<FormState>();

  return showDialog<void>(

    context: context,

    barrierDismissible: true, // user must tap button!

    builder: (BuildContext context) {

      return AlertDialog(

        backgroundColor: Colors.white,

        clipBehavior: Clip.none,

        surfaceTintColor: Colors.white,

        insetPadding: const EdgeInsets.all(10),

        contentPadding:

            const EdgeInsets.symmetric(vertical: 30, horizontal: 20),

        content: SingleChildScrollView(

          child: Form(

            key: formKey,

            child: ListBody(

              children: <Widget>[

                Row(

                  children: [

                    Container(

                      width: SizeUtils.getDisplayWidth(context) * .1,

                      height: SizeUtils.getDisplayWidth(context) * .1,

                      decoration: BoxDecoration(

                        color: Theme.of(context).custom.themeColor,

                        borderRadius: BorderRadius.circular(100),

                      ),

                      child: Icon(

                        Icons.person_3_rounded,

                        color: Theme.of(context).custom.grayLightTextColor,

                      ),

                    ),

                    Padding(

                      padding: const EdgeInsets.symmetric(horizontal: 5.0),

                      child: Column(

                        children: [

                          const Text(

                            "",

                            style: TextStyle(

                              fontWeight: FontWeight.w600,

                              fontSize: 14,

                            ),

                          ),

                          Text(

                            DateTime.now().convertToReadableDate(),

                            style: TextStyle(

                                color: Colors.black.withOpacity(.3),

                                fontSize: 12),

                          ),

                        ],

                      ),

                    )

                  ],

                ),

                Center(

                  child: Padding(

                    padding: const EdgeInsets.symmetric(vertical: 8.0),

                    child: RatingBar.builder(

                      itemBuilder: (context, _) => const Icon(

                        Icons.star,

                        color: Colors.amber,

                      ),

                      onRatingUpdate: (rating) {

                        rating = review!.rating;

                        print("rating:  ${review.rating}");

                      },

                    ),

                  ),

                ),

                Padding(

                  padding: const EdgeInsets.symmetric(horizontal: 8.0),

                  child: Center(

                    child: Container(

                      margin: const EdgeInsets.symmetric(vertical: 10),

                      padding: const EdgeInsets.symmetric(horizontal: 10),

                      decoration: BoxDecoration(

                        color: Theme.of(context)

                            .custom

                            .primaryColor

                            .withOpacity(.03),

                        border: Border.all(

                            color: Theme.of(context)

                                .custom

                                .themeColor

                                .withOpacity(.3)),

                        borderRadius: BorderRadius.circular(5),

                      ),

                      child: TextFormField(

                        autovalidateMode: AutovalidateMode.onUserInteraction,

                        maxLines: 5,

                        onChanged: (value) {

                          review?.description = value;

                        },

controller: descriptionController,

                        validator: (value) {

                          return null;

                        },

                        decoration: InputDecoration(

                            enabledBorder: UnderlineInputBorder(

                              borderSide: BorderSide(

                                  color: Colors.white.withOpacity(0)),

                            ),

                            focusedBorder: UnderlineInputBorder(

                              borderSide: BorderSide(

                                  color: Colors.white.withOpacity(0)),

                            ),

                            hintText: "DESCRIPTION".tr()),

                      ),

                    ),

                  ),

                ),

                CustomButtonWidget(

                    title: "RATE".tr(),

                    onTap: () {

                      review?.description = descriptionController.text;

                    }),

              ],

            ),

          ),

        ),

      );

    },

  );

}
```